# how to drop and add multi constraints by 1 sql statement for H2 database

Tags: h2

I'm working on H2 database, and I meet this problem - 
to drop one constraint is fine, I can use this statement

```
alter table customer drop constraint if exists fk_customer_order ;
```

for add one constraint is fine too, I can use this statement.

```
alter table customer add constraint fk_customer_order foreign key (order_id) references order (id) on delete cascade on update cascade;
```

but the problems is, in customer table I have more foreign key and I want delete them in one query statement.
Something like this

```
alter table customer drop constraint fk_customer_order 
drop constraint fk_customer_information
drop constraint ....
```

but this seem can not be done in h2 database, anyone can tell me can or not add or drop multi constraint by 1 sql statment? Any answer are welcome and I appreciate much.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can not be done. Why don't you use multiple statements?